# Python imaplib Gmail authenticate failure

Tags: python, gmail, imap

I just ran into an issue with Python's imaplib and Gmail's authentication mechanism:

```
>>> import imaplib
>>> imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
>>> imap.authenticate('bobdole@gmail.com', 'Bob Dole likes your style!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
imaplib.error: AUTHENTICATE command error: BAD ['TODO (not supported yet) 31if3458825wff.5']
```

If authentication is unsupported, how does one log in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
>>> imap.authenticate('bobdole@gmail.com', 'Bob Dole likes your style!')
```

use

```
>>> imap.login('bobdole@gmail.com', 'Bob Dole likes your style!')
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
srv = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
srv.login(account, password)
```

I think using `login()` is required.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on [this helpful blog post](http://codeclimber.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-ruby-for-imap-with-gmail.html). Although Gmail doesn't support AUTHENTICATE, it does support the LOGIN capability, like so:

```
>>> imap.login('bobdole@gmail.com', 'Bob Dole likes your style!')
('OK', ['bobdole@gmail.com authenticated (Success)'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Python

`import imaplib
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
imap.login('bobdole@gmail.com', 'Bob Dole likes your style!')`

You don't necessarily need to use the port number also, creating the imap Session will also work like:
`imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')`